# Sails.js Policies, is there an OR operator to allow an action if one of a group of policies succeeds?

Tags: policy, sails.js

When configuring policies in sails in config/policies.js such as:

```
    ActivityController: {
        create: ['authenticated'],
        update: ['authenticated', 'isActivityOwner'],
        destroy: ['authenticated' ,'isActivityOwner']
    }
```

Is there any functionality that would allow me to grant access to the action provided one or more of a group of policies succeeds maybe something like:

```
    ActivityController: {
        create: ['authenticated'],
        update: ['authenticated', {or:['isActivityOwner', 'isAdmin']}],
        destroy: ['authenticated' ,'isActivityOwner']
    }
```

Alternatively is it possible to create composite policies so that in one policy I may check one or more other policies?

If both of these options seem like poor solutions, can you suggest an approach that would would be considered better practice?

Forgive me if this is a bit obvious but I'm fairly new to sails and node in general, and thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't found any official support for operators in sails policies but here is what I am doing.

```
ActivityController: {
    update: ['authenticated', 'orActivityOwner', 'orAdmin', orPolicy],
}
```

Both `orActivityOwner` and `orAdmin` return `next()` as if they are valid. But they also set a boolean value to a session variable. Remember, policies are executed from left to right. I added an `orPolicy` to the end which will then evaluate the state of our session variable.

Comment: This is a usable workaround but I think it's a bit messy. Maybe it would be better if one could supply an object with an operator such as `{ operator: 'OR', policies: ['ActivityOwner','Admin']}`. I think that  would be more flexible. I'll take a peek at the code and maybe ask the sails team if they would be interested in this approach. Thanks for the workaround though!

Comment: Excellent Workaround. You can also chooser parts that are absolutely required for instance: isLoggedIn you can just hit the res.redirect right there, and any other policies that are "Or" keeps getting passed until it hits orPolicy for evaluation.

Comment: you advice force to provide a lot of files in policy directory. For each right you have to create Or, And, Is. So if you have for example admin and user  it will have 6 separate rights.

Comment: Good solution @Travis

Answer (score 7):

check out [sails-must](http://github.com/cludden/sails-must):

```
ActivityController: {
    create: 'authenticated',
    update: ['authenticated', must().be.the.owner.or.be.a.member.of('admins')],
    destroy: ['authenticated', must().be.the.owner]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've created a sails hook to be able to add parameters to policies:
https://github.com/mastilver/sails-hook-parametized-policies

I've setup an example where I defined an `or` policy:

```
module.exports = function(firstPolicy, secondPolicy){

    return function(req, res, next){


        var fakeRes = {};

        for(var i in res){
            if(i === 'forbidden'){
                // override the functions you want the `or` factory to handle
                fakeRes[i] = function(){
                    secondPolicy(req, res, next);
                };
            }
            else{
                fakeRes[i] = res[i];
            }
        }


        firstPolicy(req, fakeRes, next);
    }
}
```

Which you can use that way:

```
ActivityController: {
        create: ['authenticated'],
        update: ['authenticated', 'or(isActivityOwner, isAdmin)'],
        destroy: ['authenticated' ,'isActivityOwner']
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is workable. I've made minor modifications to your code, which provide ability to pass thirdPolicy. https://gist.github.com/1nstinct/12399f8adc4e5cfd6e88

Comment: @1nstinct the ideal would be to use a recursive function so it can handle as many policy as possible
Feels free to send me a PR to update the readme

Comment: @1nstinct Pull request on Github

Comment: @mastilver I've made modifications, that provide ability to send any count of policies as arguments. https://gist.github.com/1nstinct/12399f8adc4e5cfd6e88

Comment: @1nstinct Could you send me pull request to https://github.com/mastilver/sails-hook-parametized-policies to update the readme (easier to talk there)

Just replace my `or.js` example with a link to your gist

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the previous answer, that works like a charm :

---

#### Piece of information

> But they also set a boolean value to a session variable

I myself prefer setting this boolean to the `req` object, that :

- Is more semantic (access granted or not to ressource for the **request**, not for entire **session**)
- Does not requires me to manually reset this variable
  (I should add that, if you DO want to use session like in @Travis solution , the last `orPolicy` policy must reset (even unset) the `variable` in order to protect the next request)

#### My implementation

*config/policies.js* :

```
MyController: {
  find: ['orIsTest1', 'orIsTest2', 'protectedResourceGranted']
}
```

*api/policies/orIsTest1.js* :

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  req.protectedResourceGranted = req.protectedResourceGranted || WHATEVERFIRSTTEST;

  return next();
};
```

*api/policies/orIsTest2.js*

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  req.protectedResourceGranted = req.protectedResourceGranted || WHATEVERSECONDTEST;

  return next();
};
```

*api/policies/protectedResourceGranted.js*

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.protectedResourceGranted) {
    return next();
  }

  return res.forbidden();
};
```

---

*NB: Just answering 'cause I haven't got enough reputation to comment.*

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here work great, but here is an implementation that I find slightly cleaner.

Instead of creating policies designed for an *OR* situation that call `next()` even though they should fail, you can **modify your existing policies to use in an *AND*/*OR* context**, while hardly changing their behavior. Then create a composite policy (like the OP suggested) that checks the modified existing policies.

*config/policies.js* with example controllers and policies:

```
AdminController: {
  adminDashboard: 'isAuthenticated',
},

ItemController: {
  findOne: 'isPublishedOrIsAuthenticated'
}
```

*api/policies/isAuthenticated.js* and *api/policies/isPublished.js* and any other policy you want to use as a part of an *AND*/*OR* check:

If `next` was set to the `true` boolean (as opposed to a callback), just return `true` or `false` before the policy would normally return `next()`, `res.notFound()`, etc.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  // do some checking
  if(next === true) return true; // or return false
  return next();
};
```

Note that we need to use the [triple-equals](http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/) sign here.

*api/policies/isPublishedOrIsAuthenticated.js*

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  var isPublished = require('./isPublished.js');
  var isAuthenticated = require('./isAuthenticated.js');

  // This reads like what we are trying to achieve!
  // The third argument in each call tells the function to return a boolean
  if(isPublished(req, res, true) || isAuthenticated(req, res, true))
    return next();

  return res.notFound();
};
```

Comment: Someone knows any better way than `require` to manualy invoke a policy